# How to filter tasks on infopath form load?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, tasks, custom-list-actions

I want show infopath task list data according to the action item one by one on infopath form load. All items showing on the form load tasks which are created in a task list. I applied the rule on form load but it not get filtering the action items. Is there any idea how can resolve this issues on form load?

Answer (score 0):

Your question indicates you are using SPO.  If so, you should use PowerApps or Forms for this rather than Infopath; it's deprecated and not built for the Online platform.

Comment: I am using InfoPath form.

Comment: Then you're building a dead-end legacy relic that is not sustainable. It is not supported in O365/SharePoint Online.